# prove that $\{a_{n}\} $ converges as $, a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}}{sin(a_{n})},\ \forall n\geq2$ and $0<a_{1}<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

let $\{a_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a sequence defined as $$0<a_{1}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and          $$ a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}}{\sin(a_{n})},\ \forall n\geq2$$

prove that $\{a_{n}\} $ converges, and find the limit of $\{a_{n}\}$.

Comment: Hint: $\sin x \sim x$ near $0$

Comment: problem is this is not a monotonic sequence so i can't find a way to demonstrate that it convergences. i mean, how to prove that $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is an upper bound?

Comment: @Jneven How is it not monotonic?

Comment: $x\mapsto f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is a contraction of the metric space $I=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution in $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the limit is easy: set $a_{n+1}=a_n=\alpha$, and we get:
$$\alpha=\frac{\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$
We get $\sin\alpha=1$, which leads to $\alpha=\frac\pi2$

So it converges to $\frac\pi2$.

To prove it's convergence, show that when you start with $0<a_1<\frac{\pi}{2}$, that $a_{n+1}>a_n\forall n$ (It is as shown [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rkut9a7v15))

Comment: -1: This answer does not prove convergence. What if $a_n \gt \pi$ such that $\sin a_n \lt 0$? Also monotonicity is not enough, you need to show boundedness too.

Comment: @Aryabhata, look at the graph.

Comment: Or, simply set an $a_1$ within the boundaries given, e.g. $a_1=\frac\pi4$ and try iterating it. It's enough in this case, to show that it increases, knowing that it will slow as it approaches $a_n=\frac\pi2$

Comment: "Look at the graph" is not a proof. Sorry for being pedantic.

Comment: @Aryabhata, what I'm saying is, if you look at the graph, you see what happens, the graph increases constantly from $(0,1)$ to $(\frac\pi2, \frac \pi2)$, so verifying that algebraically serves as proof enough.

Comment: What I'm saying is: the "verifying algebraically" needs to be part of the answer. (Again, I am being pedantic here).